# SQL DELETE using DATE

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sql-delete

```
    CUSTOMER(CustID, CustName)
    Sale(SaleNo, StockNo, CustNo, SaleDate)
```

How do I delete customers that have not bought anything since 2009?

i can get the CustID's by using a minus

```
    SELECT CustID FROM CUSTOMER
    WHERE SaleDate <= to_date('31-12-09', 'DD-MM-YY')
    MINUS
    SELECT CustID FROM CUSTOMER
    WHERE SaleDate > to_date('31-12-09', 'DD-MM-YY');
```

But I have no idea how I would do the delete in a single query.

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: You need something like this " DELETE FROM CUSTOMER WHERE SaleDate NOT BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE('expr for 2009')";

Comment: What is your database server? How are Customer and Sale table link? It seems like `CUSTOMER.CustID` correspond to `Sale.CustNo`. If so please add this information.

Comment: Your example statement cannot possibly run because your `customer` table does not contain the `SaleDate` column.

Comment: it should have been CustId in Sale, Not CustNo. It is Oracle DB. Will try Luv's suggestion, it looks like what I am after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>You didn't specify your DBMS although I suspect it's Oracle due to the use of `MINUS` and `to_date()`</sup>

Anyway the following should work on Oracle (and any DBMS that complies with the ANSI standard)

```
delete from customer
where not exists (select 1 
                  from sale
                  where sale.custId = customer.CustNo
                    and sale.saledate >= date '2009-01-01')
```

Comment: This one works, trying to activate the tick but nothing is happening, will keep trying. Thanks a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 3):

```
delete from CUSTOMER c
inner join Sale S 
on C.CustID=S.CustNo
where max(SaleDate)<='31-12-09'
```

Comment: That wouldn't work on Oracle, I think, and the "where max(SaleDate)" clause looks like it might not work on any RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server

```
DELETE FROM Customer
WHERE CustID IN ( SELECT CustNo FROM Sale 
                  GROUP BY CustNo
                  HAVING YEAR(MAX(SaleDate))<2009)
```

In MySQL

```
DELETE FROM Customer
WHERE CustID IN ( SELECT CustNo FROM Sale 
                  GROUP BY CustNo
                  HAVING EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MAX(SaleDate))<2009)
```

Comment: That wouldn't cover customers who have never bought anything, though.